# Echo wp_title('') substring not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Echo wp_title('') substring not working

```
<?php
  //title = Title number 1
  $title = wp_title(''); 
  echo substr($title, 5); // Show: "Title number 1" 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `false` in for the second parameter (which defaults to `true`), since you don't want to initially display the title.

> `$display` – *(boolean)* Formats the return value either for display as text (`true`) or as a parameter for another PHP function (`false`). 
>   Default: `true`

```
$title = wp_title('', false);
```

Read more [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title).